# How can I create 2GP package version including FSL permissions

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, 2gp, second-generation-packaging, fsl

I'm using FSL Dispatcher Permissions and FSL Dispatcher License in test class for a scenario to cover code in my apex class. It worked fine when running the test class. But when doing a package version create by including them in apexTestAccess object in sfdx-project json, it is failing because they are created in the org after installing FSL package. So, is there any way to create package version successfully with those permissions included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your package is not inherently dependent on FLS you should check out the concept of [unpackaged metadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pkg2_dev.meta/pkg2_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_unpackaged_md.htm).

This allows you to have metadata in a separate package directory that the package's unit tests rely on without then needing the metadata to be packaged.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked.